# UL header text is repeating in knockout.js. How to prevent this?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application

I am using knockout js for binding data from db to UL in my Single page application.
Below is my code

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: Contacts" >
<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
Criteria Selected
</li>
<li data-theme="c">
<a href="#page3" data-transition="slide" data-bind="attr: { title: ContactID }">
<span data-bind="text: FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' (' + Classification +':'+ Position+ ')'"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
```

Its working fine. Suppose, If data from db is nearly 300 and then bind to UL successfully.

But my problem is for each data it showing header text as "Criteria Selected".For 300 data , it showing 300 header text with data. I want only one header text and below that it will display all the data from db.

Please tell me where I have to made change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` binding duplicates the entire contents of the element it is used on. You have to use [virtual elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_4_using_foreach_without_a_container_element) to achieve the desired effect.

```
<ul>
   <li>Criteria selected</li>
   <!-- ko foreach: Contacts -->
   <li>
       <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
   </li>
   <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```